# JFactory::getDate() time offsets

Tags: development, joomla-3.3.x

For this question I say "offsets" but I do not really mean timezones. What I am looking for is an offset of right "now" to 1 day, 1 week or 1 month and further in the past.

http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getDate

In the documentation it does show a timezone offset that can be an integer, which makes me thing that will work, however passing a null or false value for the first seems like it could cause an issue. I could also pass a default date object, but that seems like its taking from the benefit of using the API.

So what I want to do is kind of like follows.

```
$now = JFactory::getDate();
$now->minusOffset(24 HOURS);
$query->where('created >= \'$now->toMySQL()\'');
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Or is it best to convert a normal php date object into getDate? So far my searching has turned up nothing on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JDate` just extends `DateTime` class, so you can use anything that available for [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

something like that:

```
$yesterday = JFactory::getDate('now -1 day');
```

or use [modify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

```
$now = JFactory::getDate();
$now->modify('-1 day');
```

Comment: Perfect! this really helps me understand better how the date class was built.